# return a boolean value with a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is my code:

const executorFunction = (resolve, reject) => {

```
<script>
      
if (  1==1){

    resolve(true);
   
}
else{
    resolve(false);
}

    }




const myFirstPromise = new Promise(executorFunction);


console.log(myFirstPromise);


        </script>
```

Here is the output of my code:

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: true}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: true
```

I want the boolean value true in the variable myFirstPromise

and i want this output:

```
true
```

What is the solution please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `then`. Also the `script` tag inside the `executorFunction` function does not make any sense

```js
const executorFunction = (resolve, reject) => {
  if (1 === 1) {
   resolve(true);
  } else {
    resolve(false);
  }

}
const myFirstPromise = new Promise(executorFunction);

myFirstPromise.then(d => console.log(d))
```

> how I can get the boolean value true in a variable out of the function

That may not be possible directly with Promise, instead you can use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Internally this also returns a Promise

```js
function executorFunction() {
  return 1 ? true : false;
}

async function getVal() {
  const val = await executorFunction();
  console.log(val)
}

getVal()
```

Comment: Alternatively you may be able to use `async/await`, depending on the browsers you're supporting.

Comment: ok thanks but how  I can get the  boolean value true  in a variable out of the function myFirstPromise.then(d => console.log(d))              ??

Comment: @geekdu972 check updated code